# How to determine the angle of the image to check whether the image is vertical or horizontal?

Tags: python, image, opencv, rotation, orientation

I'm trying to align all images as vertical/horizontal. I got to rotate the image using the following code:

```py
import cv2
import imutils
import numpy as np
def rotate_bound(image, angle):
    # grab the dimensions of the image and then determine the
    # center
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
    (cX, cY) = (w // 2, h // 2)
    # grab the rotation matrix (applying the negative of the
    # angle to rotate clockwise), then grab the sine and cosine
    # (i.e., the rotation components of the matrix)
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cX, cY), -angle, 1.0)
    cos = np.abs(M[0, 0])
    sin = np.abs(M[0, 1])
    # compute the new bounding dimensions of the image
    nW = int((h * sin) + (w * cos))
    nH = int((h * cos) + (w * sin))
    # adjust the rotation matrix to take into account translation
    M[0, 2] += (nW / 2) - cX
    M[1, 2] += (nH / 2) - cY
    # perform the actual rotation and return the image
    return cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (nW, nH))
image = cv2.imread("10247.png")
# loop over the rotation angles again, this time ensuring
# no part of the image is cut off
dim=(600,400)
im=rotate_bound(image,30)
im = cv2.resize(im, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
cv2.imshow("Rotated (Correct)", im)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyWindow("Rotated (Correct)")
for angle in np.arange(0, 360, 15):
    rotated = imutils.rotate_bound(image, angle)
    dim=(800,600)
    resized = cv2.resize(rotated, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
    cv2.imshow("Rotated (Correct)", resized)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyWindow("Rotated (Correct)")
```

I want the rotation to stop when the image is vertical/horizontal. How do I stop it? How to determine the current angle?

[image: Original Image]

[image: How it should be]

Comment: you will have to introduce some top-down knowledge and detect it in the image. e,g. you could search the image border regions for the "big bright arm part" and rotate the image until it is in the center of the bottom of the image. Or you could try to detect the fingers (e.g. with convexityDefects function) and rotate until they are the the top, centered.

Comment: @nathancy I tried all the methods you mentioned to check the angle and i've been getting the wrong result. I need the image to be rotated around 30 degree but i get around 260 degree using the above method.

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce some [AI using MediaPipe](https://ai.googleblog.com/2019/08/on-device-real-time-hand-tracking-with.html). From there you get the landmarks for the fingers and rotate, e.g. index finger up.

A similar operation could be to transform the image to black-white and use the [morphological operation](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/courses/compsci773s1c/lectures/ImageProcessing-html/topic4.htm) *erosion* to shrink the arm down to mere lines.

Then use the *Hough Line Transform* to get the fingers, sort them (left to right), get the angle to the vertical of the index finger and rotate.